# Для чего предназначены SSH ключи на github?

Tags: github

Я правильно понимаю что SSH ключи нужны для того что бы совместно с кем то работать с кодом?
Смотрю западные курсы, там показали как настраивать ключи, но смысл так до конца не уловил
То есть сбрасываешь id.rsa.pub другому человеку и вперед

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для авторизации. Закинул свой публичный ключ, и затем на своем устройстве можешь авторизовываться без пароля.

Так же можно и с авторизацией на сервере, посмотрите консольную команду `ssh-copy-id`

С её помощью можете один раз авторизоваться и она за вас закинет ключ на сервер.

Comment: А как совместно работать над кодом с кем то?

Comment: @Sinevik это никак не связано с ssh-ключами

Comment: Смотря что вы понимаете под "совместно". Есть много вариантов, например: 1) можно онлайн редактировать один и тот же код VS Code и Atom имеют для этого очень удобные плагины. 2) можно вести совместный проект на гитхабе (читайте, или ищите ответы для чего это нужно), если хотите писать код и что бы никто его не видел, то сразу идите на bitbucket, там можно бесплатно создать закрытый репозиторий @Sinevik